# Wordpress - fetch user info using jQuery ajax POST request

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am working in Wordpress trying to use an ajax request to fetch user data by passing the user id.

I can see that the user id sends correctly via AJAX POST but I am getting an internal error message and I don't know why.

At first I thought it was because I was trying to fetch some custom fields that I had added to the user profile but even when I simplified my script I am still getting the error message.

Any help is much appreciated!

**Front End**

```
$('.author').click(function() {

    var id   = $(this).attr('id');
    var temp = id.split('-');
    id = temp[1];

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/author_info.php',
            data: {id: id},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#author-bio').html(data);        
            }
        });     

    return false;
});
```

**author_info.php**

```
$user_id = $_POST['id'];
$forename = get_the_author_meta('user_firstname', $user_id);
$output = $user_id;
echo $output;
```

**Error Message**

`500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:4`

Comment: This is not even the right approach to use ajax in Wordpress. Would you like to see the correct method?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Why else would he ask the question if not to get a correct answer?

Comment: @Jason Towne because 'best practice' != 'it works'.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Fair enough. If someone knows how to answer the question using best practices, I would assume they would provide that answer instead of something that 'just works'. After all, you never know *who's* code you will have to maintain. :)

Comment: yes please @ohgodwhy, I am a wordpress n00b so I didn't even know that there was another approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathieu added a hackable approach to intercepting a request and redirecting it, which is fine. I prefer to build out AJAX responses that return `json_encoded` arrays.

```
$('.author').click(function() {

  var id   = $(this).attr('id');
  var temp = id.split('-');
  id = temp[1];

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://absolute.path/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {'action' : 'ajax_request', 'fn': 'getAuthorMeta', 'id': id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //We expect a JSON encoded array here, not an HTML template.       
    }
  });     
  return false;
});
```

Now we build out the function to handle our ajax requests.

First, we need to define our ajax add_action method ->

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');
```

We need to use both `add_action` lines here. I won't get into why. You'll notice the `_ajax_request` here. This is the 'action' that we sent over in our AJAX function `data: {'action' : 'ajax_request'}`. We use this hook to validate our AJAX request, it can be anything you'd like.

Next, we'll need to build out or function `ajax_handle_request`.

```
function ajax_handle_request(){
  switch($_REQUEST['fn']){
    case 'getAuthorMeta':
      $output = ajax_get_author_meta($_REQUEST['id']);
      break;
    default:
      $output = 'That is not a valid FN parameter. Please check your string and try again';
      break;
  }
  $output = json_encode($output);
  if(is_array($output)){
    return $output;
  }else{
    echo $output;
  }
}
```

Now let's build our function to actually get the author meta.

```
function ajax_get_author_meta($id){
  $theMeta = get_the_author_meta([meta_option], $id);
  return $theMeta;
}
```

Where [meta_option] is [a field provided by WP's native get_the_author_meta function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta).

At this point, we'll now go back to our `success:function(data)` and (data) is a reference to the `json_encoded` array we've returned. We can now iterate over the object to get our fields and output them into the page as you'd like.

Comment: thanks, getting an error at the moment though. Just to clarfiy, the `add_action` and `function ajax_handle_request(){` are to be placed in `functions.php` and the last function, `function ajax_get_author_meta($id){` should go in `author_info.php`?

Comment: All these functions should be in functions.php. There's no need for author_info.php.

Comment: ok, just did that and my page doesn't load as soon as that last function is pasted into functions.php. Also, if there is no need for the separate ajax file, why is the url of the ajax request still pointing to it? - `url: 'http://absolute.path/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/author_info.php',`

Comment: @martincarlin87 Oops! Really sorry about that, and you're totally right. The `URL` should be `url: 'http://absolute.path/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',`

Comment: ah, excellent, thank you for your help. The only question I have now is do you happen to have an example of what to do in the success function to output the data? At the moment I have tried `$('#author-bio').val(data);` just to get some output but not sure if that will work or if the JSON will need parsed first.

Comment: @martincarlin87 Now that you've got the JSON returned, you need to iterate over the object to get it's `key => value` parsed. `$.each(data, function(index, obj){ $('#author-bio').val(obj.user_nicename) });` Where user_nicename is a field provided by [get_the_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)

Comment: thank you, the value is still not showing just now even though it is being returned correctly by the ajax request but I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14355/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-martincarlin87)

Answer (score 2):

You are not in a POST at that moment because you are calling a specific page of your template that probably doesn't correspond to any article in your blog.

Instead, create a pluggin that will do this:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_author_meta_intercept');
function my_author_meta_intercept(){
    if(isset($_POST['getAuthorMeta'])){
        echo get_the_author_meta('user_firstname', $_POST['getAuthorMeta']);
        exit();
    }
}
```

This will short circuit the request to the same page as before when you call it using:

```
http://mysite/mycurrenturl?getAuthorMeta=testMetaKey
```

So calling that post normally will return the article as usual, but if you pass in ?getAuthorMeta, it will stop the template from being selected and simply return the exact content you want it to return.

In your page, you just have to change your javascript to:

```
$('.author').click(function() {

    var id   = $(this).attr('id');
    var temp = id.split('-');
    id = temp[1];

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.location.href,
            data: {getAuthorMeta: id},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#author-bio').html(data);        
            }
        });     

    return false;
});
```

Just make sure you adapt the concept to what you need!

Comment: Also note, you have used "POST" as a method to "GET" information, please read on the subjet, "POST" is reserved for state changes on the server while "GET" is used to query for information. So you should always use GET in AJAX calls if you want to get data. But if you need to change the state of the server, it should be a POST

Answer (score 2):

I would rather recommend you to use [WP AJAX action method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29).

As in your case, add the following to your functions.php file.

```
 add_action('wp_ajax_get_user_info', 'ajax_get_user_info');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_user_info', 'ajax_get_user_info');

 function ajax_get_user_info() {
    //Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response or your html.
 }
```

then in javascript tag.

```
$('.author').click(function() {

    var id   = $(this).attr('id');
    var temp = id.split('-');
    id = temp[1];

jQuery.post(
   ajaxurl,  /* if you get error of undefined ajaxurl. set it to "http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"*/
   {
      'action':'get_user_info',
      'user_id':id
   }, 
   function(response){
      alert('The server responded: ' + response);
   }
);
});
```

I would recommend you to read the [5 tips for using AJAX in WordPress](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress).

p.s; Code above is not tested, it may have errors. but you get the idea.

Comment: see my post for the long form version of this!