# AJAX not returning anything - Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Basing my code on the accepted answer here:

[Wordpress - fetch user info using jQuery ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633739/wordpress-fetch-user-info-using-jquery-ajax-post-request)

header.php

```
<?php $admin_ajax_path = ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; ?>

<script>
  var absAjaxPath = "<?php echo $admin_ajax_path; ?>";
</script>
```

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_request', 'ajax_handle_request');

function ajax_handle_request(){
  switch($_REQUEST['fn']){
    case 'getUserMeta':
      $output = ajax_user_meta($_REQUEST['id']);
      break;
    default:
      $output = 'That is not a valid FN parameter. Please check your string and try again';
      break;
  }
  $output = json_encode($output);
  if(is_array($output)){
    return $output;
  }else{
    echo $output;
  }
die();
}

function ajax_user_meta($id){
    $theMeta = get_user_meta( $id, 'tel', true );
  return $theMeta;
}
```

my js file

```
jQuery('.list-group-item').click(function() {

  var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://sub.domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    url: absAjaxPath, //this one returns a not found error
    data: {'action' : 'ajax_request', 'fn': 'getUserMeta', 'id': id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //We expect a JSON encoded array here, not an HTML template.
      alert(data);
    }
  });     
  return false;
});
```

The `alert(id)` triggers once I click an element with an id set to `2`. I have a user set up with that id. Other than that, nothing happens. Shouldn't the `alert(data)` in the ajax success function trigger?

Comment: Have you checked developer's console? What's the server response?

Comment: I didn't until now. Thank you. It's returning `""0`

Comment: Now find out what part of code return `""` and what `0`

Comment: Seems to be `echo $output;` ... weird, I added `return "hello";` instead of `return $theMeta;` and not it's returning `"hello"0`. I wonder where that 0 is from. But does that mean that this: `$theMeta = get_user_meta( $id, 'tel', true );` isn't the way to get user meta? It s right out of codex.

Comment: Maybe @Ohgodwhy can lend a helping hand with this.

Comment: @ciprian that is because any output you want to send back has to be echo'd out, not returned. The 0 at the end is because you aren't putting `die()` at the end of the function.

Comment: $theMeta = get_user_meta( $id, 'tel', true ); is the way to get the meta, but apparently the user with ID 2 doesn't have a meta value 'tel'.

Comment: @bobdye you re 100% right. the user that has `tel` has id 4

Comment: @JesseKernaghan i edited the function in my question. please take a look. it s still returning 0

Comment: @ciprian you've added it to the wrong function, unfortunately. It should die after you echo `$output`. Other than that it should work. Are you sure that the current user has meta 'tel'?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan ... my mistake. So it should be after the `return` and the `echo` correct? I solved the `tel` problem. The user didn't have it set. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @ciprian after that if/else block, yes. Generally you want it to be the very last line of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `die();` or `exit();` to a very last line of your PHP function which you call via AJAX to prevent returning `0`.

Comment: You mean after `return $theMeta;` ? I did. die and exit and it's still returning 0

Comment: Should be in `ajax_handle_request()` in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove `dataType:'json'`
let ajax to automatically detect

Comment: Did the trick for me. Thanks!